# Converting Digital Image From SQL Server 2012 To Physical Image

Tags: sql-server

I have an `Image` table which contains around 50000 images in a SQL Server 2012 database. Now I need to migrate all images from database to physical image in a specified folder.

I have used the code shown below to migrate the image but only 12000 images are converted to clear format others all are distorted blur or unclear. Problem is when we see this image from software we are using is very clear and perfect. So please any one help me how to migrate the binary image to physical image as it seen from software used.

Please review the SQL code I have used:

```
DECLARE 
    @FileContent VARBINARY(MAX),
    @FileName VARCHAR(MAX),
    @ObjectToken INT,
    @FileID VARCHAR(MAX),
    @IsApproved VARCHAR(2),
    @PicT VARCHAR(1)

DECLARE cFiles CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT I.Code, I.Name, Image, IsApproved, PicType 
    FROM ImageTable I

OPEN cFiles

FETCH NEXT FROM cFiles 
      INTO @FileID, @FileName, @FileContent,@IsApproved, @PicT

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    -- CHOOSE 1 of these SET statements:

    -- if FileName is unique, then just remove special characters
    SET @FileName = REPLACE(REPLACE(@FileName, '\', ' '), ':', ' ')

    -- if FileName without path information is unique
    SET @FileName = SUBSTRING(@FileName,
        len(@FileName)+2-CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@FileName)),len(@FileName))

    -- if you just take ID + extensions
    SET @FileName = CASE WHEN @PicT ='J' THEN 'D:\IMAGE\' + CAST(@FileID AS varchar) + '.jpg'
                   WHEN @PicT='B' THEN 'D:\IMAGE\' + CAST(@FileID AS varchar) + '.bmp'
                    END

    EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
    EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @FileContent
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @FileName, 2
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken

    FETCH NEXT FROM cFiles 
          INTO @FileID, @FileName, @FileContent, @IsApproved, @PicT
END

CLOSE cFiles
DEALLOCATE cFiles
```

Comment: Questions: **1** Nowhere do I see you checking the `HRESULT` that is returned from calling the `sp_OAMethod` procedure. Do any of the `HRESULT` values differ from 0 (ie `S_OK`)? **2** What is the exact method for displaying the results in your software product (minimal, complete)?

Comment: I haven't checked as mentioned. And I dont have access to software code but it show image in pop window its windows form.

Comment: You'll have to investigate the binary data and see what the cause is. Exporting files the way you are doing it, doesn't modify or transform any data. The software you speak of is obviously making making a transformation or uses an off-beat format.

Comment: So can u please guide me further process. On what site shall I focused to resolve issue in point basis. It will be great

Comment: can you please guide to export the image in MSSQL with transforming data.

Comment: The only thing I can say is that your export routine from SQL Server is correct. Ie, using an `ADODB.Stream` to export files the way you are doing it is correct. You will have to consult the software that displays the images to know what format they need to be saved in. Consult the documentation, contact the developers etc. I am by no means an expert in imaging and image formats, so I cannot help you any further.

Comment: Thanks I will proceed accordingly.